# Initiate CSS3 transitions on click - Wilto Image slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm using a content slider: https://github.com/Wilto/Dynamic-Carousel/

When I click the next/prev buttons (or when the pagination is clicked) I'd like to control how the content of each slider animates in/out using CSS3 transitions.

All I want is some very basic transitions, so the icon slides in a second or before the text, with a bit of easing thrown in. I'm confident I can do the CSS bit, its just playing it per slide, on click. I'm not that great with jquery.

How do I do this?

Here's my slider so far: http://jsfiddle.net/sVKQM/

```
//
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a pure CSS solution isn't possible since you are using a container with 500% with and just move it around. So you can apply a translation on the container and when moving it left and right, you see it nicely, however the content inside the container doesn't get modified.

So there isn't a way you can do it only with CSS because the image and Text aren't 'modified', only the container, but id, as already said doesn't propagate it to to image and Text.

PS: Feel free to prove me wrong ;)

Comment: I wasn't looking for a pure CSS solution but to combine CSS3 transitions with the slider I have already